# Парсинг данных с помощью JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

С помощью JSoup хочу получить значение "href" (нужно получить значение "11"). Как это сделать?

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?--><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="page page_js_no ">
 <body id="dik" class="page__body _hover dik_stickers_hints_support_no opera_mini_no dik_al_no"> 
  <div class="layout"> 
   <div class="layout__body " id="dik_wrap"> 
    <div class="layout__basis" id="m">
     <div class="basis"> 
      <div class="basis__header mhead" id="mhead">
       <a href="/id11" accesskey="*" class="hb_wrap mhb_home mhb_dikhome">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно лишь получить первый элемент по имени его класса и взять его атрибут так:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

String href = doc.getElementsByClass("hb_wrap mhb_home mhb_dikhome").get(0).attr("href");
```

Comment: Ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Получилось вот так: String href = doc.getElementsByClass("hb_wrap").get(0).attr("href"); Убрал пробелы.